# Cast string to date Java

Tags: java

Any ideas why this isnt working?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
    String start, finish;
    System.out.println("Please enter a start date:");
    while(date1 == null){
        try{
            start = scan.next();
            date1 = (Date) df.parse(start);
        }catch(ParseException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid date!");
        }
    }
```

Im getting a classCastException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

I can't see the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're importing `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Thank you! Will look out for this in the future

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
import java.sql.Date
```

somewhere up top.  Gotta be careful about the two `Date` classes; they aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to use java.util.Date instead just Date:

```
Java.util.DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Java.util.Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
    String start, finish;
    System.out.println("Please enter a start date:");
    while(date1 == null){
        try{
            start = scan.next();
            date1 = (Java.util.Date) df.parse(start);
        }catch(ParseException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid date!");
        }
    }
```